# Where to find parallel English-Russian novels to learn Russian?

Tags: resources, обучение, литература

Where can I find licence-free dual language English-Russian novels?  I think this is one of the most effective way of learning language, because of no time needed to search words in dictionary, and the translation is always before eyes. However, finding such books is a bit challenge. I've found the multi-language Bible, but this kind of literature isn't appealing to me.

The best would be science-fiction novels, but everything else except romances would be also fine.

Comment: To start with have a look through the Russian Readers section on amazon,  Although looking at it, it's pretty poor.  It's an old one but I enjoyed Bondar's annotated Queen of Hearts by Pushkin.

Comment: Why must these novels be license-free? There is a book of translations called Russian Stories: a Dual Language Book, edited by Gleb Struve, which you can find on amazon.

Comment: Well, not exactly licence-free, but the ones I need not pay for ;)

Comment: I found [Russian Stories: A Dual-Language Book](http://www.amazon.com/Russian-Stories-Dual-Language-English-Edition/dp/0486262448) interesting.

Comment: Surprised nobody had mentioned this one - http://franklang.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=2&Itemid=42  - Oh, sorry, it turns out it is mainly not free.

Comment: A list of ~150 books with parallel translation - https://studyenglishwords.com/book - sort by Genre, science-fiction = Фантастика

Comment: Not exactly sci-fi, but Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality are available in both English as well as Russian (and probably other languages). http://hpmor.com/ vs http://hpmor.ru/, respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Moshkow library](http://lib.ru) has explicit sections for [genres in English translation](http://www.lib.ru/TRANSLATION/). It also often includes English translations alongside Russian novels where the rights to such can be obtained. A lot of Soviet-era and older novels can be found there, for which the Russian texts are naturally also available alongside.

Answer (score 2):

This [collection of parallel text articles](http://www.scribd.com/collections/2316116/english-russian-parallel-texts) may be of interest.

This [website for Russians studying English](http://englishtexts.ru/tag/text) has some parallel text articles that look quite good.

The [browser extension Franker](http://code.google.com/p/franker/), available for Safari and Chrome, injects Google Translate translations after each sentence. Machine translation is notoriously wonky, but you should be able to get the gist of what's written. Using it on Russian, rather than English, pages should yield the best results.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this resource: http://www.moviesubtitles.ru/ (http://subtitry.ru/). As well as this one: http://www.dailyscript.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ruslan and Ludmila in Russian:
http://public-library.ru/Pushkin.Alexander/ruslan.html

In English:
http://web.archive.org/web/20060104082442re_/www.sunbirds.com/lacquer/readings/1015

There are other translations, but this one seems the most readable.